# Error while reading mail from pop3client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pop3

I am trying to read emails from pop3clent with following code:

```
Pop3Client pop = new Pop3Client();

pop.Connect(mailHost, portNum, false);
pop.Authenticate(userName, passWord,AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
```

And I am getting error while authenticating:

```
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
```

Comment: Please paste the full stacktrace.  
I believe either `mailHost` is null. Debug and check.

Comment: No mailHost is not null. I have set the value.

Answer (score 0):

You might be getting the error elsewhere if you are sure all your objects in the code you posted does not contain null values.

Comment: I debugged step by step and error occurs while authenticating. Stacktrace is;

 at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.CheckFailedLoginServerResponse(String serverErrorResponse, PopServerException e)
   at OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.Authenticate(String username, String password, AuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod)
   at{{projectPath}}

Comment: you might be getting that error if your credentials to that mail server is incorrect, or if your mail server is not configured to allow connections from other application. Are you using google mail?

Comment: If you are using google, make sure that POP is enabled for all mail. You can set this on Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP, and selecting Enable POP for all mail, then save changes. You might also want to look at https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions if you're using google and enable/disable particular applications accessing your mail server